# Error: Permission denied to access property "document"

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, xss, access-control

I have a HTML Document which contains an `iframe`. Whenever I try to access or modify this `iframe` with JS I get `Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`.

I am using `frame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML` or `frame.contentWindow.document.body.onload` or similar such attributes to access or modify the `iframe`. (In the given code the `iframe` is referred to as `frame`.)

For the web-app I am developing, access to these attributes are necessary and I can't do without these (or similar alternatives).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can still bypass this issue with the help of YQL even though you don't have access to the header part of the receiving window. With the Postmessage method also you need to edit the recipient window script. But using this method you can load any iframe without touching their scripts. Check this out!

```
<html>
<iframe src="https://google.com/" width="500" height="300"></iframe>

<script>
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var url = iframe.src;
var getData = function (data) {
    if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.resources && data.query.results.resources.content && data.query.results.resources.status == 200) loadHTML(data.query.results.resources.content);
    else if (data && data.error && data.error.description) loadHTML(data.error.description);
    else loadHTML('Error: Cannot load ' + url);
};
var loadURL = function (src) {
    url = src;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.headers%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=getData';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
var loadHTML = function (html) {
    iframe.src = 'about:blank';
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html.replace(/<head>/i, '<head><base href="' + url + '"><scr' + 'ipt>document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") { e.preventDefault(); parent.loadURL(e.target.href); } });</scr' + 'ipt>'));
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}

loadURL(iframe.src);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm impressed by this bypass. Definitely something that should be used when demonstrating Cross Frame Scripting vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yeah obviously! that part is handling by yahoo APIs :)

Comment: But i cannot use this method `iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` by using above answer. Can u pls help me?

Comment: From January '19, Yahoo has discontinued yql. You may need to use some alternative now.

Comment: @Sagar Solanki Which alternatives can be used?

Comment: @FilipŠ Haven't tried anything yet! May be you can have a look at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18785255 or https://siftery.com/yahoo-query-language-yql/alternatives

Answer (score 31):

Accessing and then modifying webpages in `iframe`s of other websites is known as [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or <kbd>XSS</kbd> and it is a technique used by malicious hackers to prey on unsuspecting victims.

A policy by the name of "Same-Origin Policy" is implemented by browser makers to prevent such behaviour and arbitrary execution of JS code.

This error can be prevented by hosting the parent document and the document in the `iframe` in the same domain and subdomain, and making sure that the documents are loaded using the same protocol.

Examples of Incompatible Pages:

1. `http://www.example.org` & `http://www.example2.com`
2. `http://abc.example.org` & `http://xyz.example.com`
3. `http://www.example.org` & `https://www.example.com`

---

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS) is a solution to this problem.

For Example:
If `http://www.example.com` would like to share `http://www.example.com/hello` with `http://www.example.org`, a header can be sent with the document which looks like the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.org
```

To send it with HTML just put it in a `<META HTTP-EQUIV="...">` tag, like this:

```
<head>
    ...
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CONTENT="http://www.example.org">
    ...
</head>
```

Comment: What if I don't have access to the "head" part of the page? I'm trying to embed a widget into Squarespace.

Comment: @PJBrunet Unfortunately, you are out of luck... I may be able to help you if you give the details about the widget and what you are trying to modify.

Comment: I'd rather not chat here, which StackOverflow frowns on. Squarespace indeed allows access to "head" however your solution didn't help because I'm on another domain. I ended up solving my problem changing the URL of the iframe after an event, and then the new iframe URL included my parameters like zipcode=12345

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might want to test these examples. I think your solution only works for subdomains and such. I don't think access control works between .org and .com (for example Bitcoin.com is the adversary of Bitcoin.org) but I don't work with iframes often, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @PJBrunet I'll look into it.

Comment: I think you should leave .org out of the examples. Yes .com is a different domain from .org, but I think your solution "access control" only works with subdomains and subdirectories.

Comment: can some one check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518384/securityerror-permission-denied-to-access-property-on-cross-origin-object-larav

Answer (score 14):

You can use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Window 1 - receiving

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
  var origin = event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin; 
  // For Chrome, the origin property is in the event.originalEvent object.
  if (origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  // ...
}
```

Window - 2 Transmitting

```
var popup = window.open(...popup details...);
popup.postMessage(
       "The user is 'bob' and the password is 'secret'", 
       "https://secure.example.net"
);
```

You have to create another pair to intercommunicate.