# How to change IFrame height to 100% of its content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I tried to make an IFrame height to 100% (like a `<div>` to `height:auto`).

I set the `height` attribute in `<iframe>` tag to 100% and set `height` in style to 100% too, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Then, I tried to use JavaScript and JQuery to get the height of `<iframe>` contents, but because of browser security reasons, it didn't got the `height` of content

How can I solve this?  I spent all day to solve this problem.

Comment: Your code , so that we can know the error ?

Comment: Does your `iframe` contain any cross domain content ?

Comment: @DanPhilip yes , it's for different domain

Comment: @IshanMahajan `$("#IframeId").load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
});`  **Error: Permission denied to access property "document"**

Comment: [This question will solve your problem for the error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333978/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document)

Comment: @IshanMahajan not worked, has same Error

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame attribute does not support percent in HTML5. It only supports pixels.
So your problem is solved using pixel value.

[How do you give iframe 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272519/how-do-you-give-iframe-100-height)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_height.asp