# Cross-origin error

Tags: html, iframe

Having an iframe embedded on a site

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" id="myIFrame" onload="frameOnload()"></iframe>
...
<script>
...
var abc = window.document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentWindow
...
</script>
```

I got an error `Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object` on line

```
var abc = window.document.getElementById("myIFrame").contentWindow
```

Even if the iframe is located on same domain ("localhost") as the parent site.
To get the code working i have to explicitly set the iframe domain like so `window.document.domain = "localhost"` in the iframe script tag.

My question is why we heve to set the iframe domain explicitly while the parent site and iframe itself live on the same domain?

Comment: May be of use for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333978/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document