# Permission denied to access the property "__contentwindow__" on cross origin object in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, iframe, printing

When I am trying to print a pdf file by loading an URL into the iframe element it throws the exception **Permission denied to access the property "__contentwindow__" on cross origin object** in the Firefox browser. But it's working good in Chrome browser

Here is the Javascript code:

```
var print = function(){

function closePrint () {
   document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}

function setPrint () {
  this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
  this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.focus(); // Required for IE
  this.contentWindow.print();
}

function printPage (sURL) {
    var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
    oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
    oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
    oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
    oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
    oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
    document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
  }
  printPage(url);
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333978/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333978/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-document) for answers.

Comment: Those answers were not helped me to solve the error

Comment: It is a security issue. Both app have to be on same origin. Or make a proxy to get it.

Comment: @Jai In fact both the domains are same. Iframe src domain will be something like "www.example.com/param1/param2" and my domain will be like "www.example.com/#/employee/"